# How can I automatically get OAuth 2.0 token and re-open my app?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I'm working with the Delivery.com API in building my app, and my current understanding of how the OAuth flow works is:

1. I redirect the user to the browser, where they explicitly sign in to their account. I supply a redirect_uri in the process.
2. Upon sign in, the user is redirected to the redirect_uri with an access token
3. I get the access token somehow, and use this to authenticate future actions in my app

It's step 3 that I'm struggling with - I've set up an `Intent` and `intent-filter` such that I correctly open the browser for step 1, and the user is correctly redirected back to my app in step 2. But this leaves two problems:

1. The redirect_uri which re-opens my app does so in the background - the browser never closes. I'm assuming there's a simple fix for this, but haven't been able to find it.
2. How do I get the access token? Is the only solution to redirect to another webpage which will display the token, and then have the user manually copy and paste this back into my app? Or can I somehow automatically get the token, re-open my app, and proceed?

**EDIT:** I was able to get this working - I'm not sure what was causing the issue in point #1 above, but after changing things back and forth a few times it started working as I originally had it. For anyone who looks into this in future, I had to include all the following elements in my `Manifest.xml` for it to work:

```
<action android:name=android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:scheme="myapp.randomname" android:host="my_url"/>
```

Regarding problem #2, I was able to parse the response by using `Uri data = getIntent().getData()` and then calling `data.getQueryParameter("fieldname")`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of launching external browser and using intent filters you should benefit more from using `WebView` directly in your app and getting thru OAuth with it.

Comment: Thanks, that's valid feedback - will look into replacing that part of the user flow.